# Streaming WebM with ffmpeg over UDP doesn't work with audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm, vorbis

I'm trying to stream a webcam video and audio as WebM via udp over the ffmpeg command line tool. (ffmpeg is build correctly and all libraries are included)

The stream is initiated with:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910":audio="Mikrofon (USB-Audogerät)" -f webm udp://localhost:11100
```

and i try to playback the file on the same computer with:

```
ffplay udp://localhost:11100
```

Streaming Video AND audio doesn't work. I get the following error message in ffplay:

```
udp://localhost:11100: End of file 0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

If i just stream the video

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910" -f webm udp://localhost:11100
```

I receive the video with ffplay.

What do i have to do to stream/receive audio correctly?

I'm trying this way with the command line to reproduce a way with using libav in a C project if this is of interest...

Comment: the only examples I have seen on the web publish through another server (ex: https://www.virag.si/2012/11/streaming-live-webm-video-with-ffmpeg)...hmm...I cannot get it to work using even just video with webm +udp...

Comment: try changing the container from Webm to flv or mpegts